# Linux Drag and Drop Files From Windows 10 to Virtual Box Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am trying to drag and drop files from Windows 10 to Virtual Box Linux.

At the top of the virtual machine in the menus I clicked devices drag and drop and then bidirectional

It shows the drop not allowed logo when trying to do it.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: It would be helpful to replace the generic Linux tag with the tag for the actual distro, because that is usually key information for a solution.  Is this Kali?  It might be useful to update the status on this one.  Were you able to get guest additions installed?

Comment: I don't remember what Linux I was using before, but the answer I checked marked below should answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and Drop -

Oracle VM VirtualBox enables you to drag and drop content from the host to the guest, and viceversa. For this to work the latest version of the Guest Additions must be installed on the guest. Drag and drop transparently allows copying or opening files,  directories,  and even certain clipboard formats from one end to the other. For example, from the host to the guest or from the guest to the host.  You then can perform drag and drop operations between the host and a VM, as it would be a native drag and drop operation on the host OS. At the moment drag and drop is implemented for Windows-based and X-Windows-based sys-tems, both on the host and guest side.  As X-Windows supports many different drag and drop protocols only the most common one,  XDND, is supported for now.  Applications using other protocols, such as Motif or OffiX, will not be recognized by Oracle VM VirtualBox. In the context of using drag and drop, the origin of the data is called the source. That is, where the actual data comes from and is specified. The target specifies where the data from the source should go to. Transferring data from the source to the target can be done in various ways, suchas copying, moving, or linking.

Comment: The other answer say ‘‘Install guest additions.’’  How does this *answer the question* any better than that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Ubuntu Guest Addittions to have this feature. To do this I suggest you to do it trought `apt`itud. It's way easier than using the image provided by Virtual Box, which  has proven to be troublesome.

Comment: @SuperUserJL Is there a virtualbox menu similar to "install guest additions"? I remember there used to be something similar. Ubuntu live ISO's often already have the guest additions included, are you using a Ubuntu live iso?